# How to add a collection to another in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In cloud firestore, I want to add the value form to collection A and then all the same value to another collection B, but collection B is inside collection A.
Currently I want to get the id of the document while adding the data to collection A and then use this.firestore.collection(A).doc(id).collection(B).add(data), but currently I cannot get the ID of the document
This one is my code to get ID when adding data to collection A.

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        let data = form.value;
        lastID = '';
        this.firestore
            .collection('Users')
            .add(data)
            .then(function (docRef) {
                this.lastID = docRef.id;
            });
        this.firestore.collection('Users').doc(lastID).collection('profile').add(data);
        this.resetForm(form);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the second add **inside** the callback of the first.  Also note that you should use an arrow function in your callback to preserve the value of `this` from the outer scope:

```
        this.firestore
            .collection('Users')
            .add(data)
            .then(docRef => {
                this.lastID = docRef.id;
                return this.firestore.collection('Users').doc(this.lastID).collection('profile').add(data);
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.resetForm(form);
            });
```

Comment: How to specify a field type? say the data should be added as string only