# how to add child collection in parent collection in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm having a problem that I can't think else how can I add another collection in the parent/first collection let say the diagram should something look like this

```
owner-item:
  group-item: [],
  single-item: []
```

Let say in `firebase-collection.js` it look something like this

```
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from './firebase'

export const owneritemsRef = collection(db,'owner-items')
```

And then now I'm exporting now the collection by something like this

```
let uploadUserStorageTask = uploadBytesResumable(list[i],pictures[j].data)
    ....
},(err) => {
    console.log(err)
},() => {
    getDownloadURL(uploadUserStorageTask.snapshot.ref)
    .then(async (downloadURL) => {
        await setDoc(doc(db,`owner-items`,`${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`),{
        creator:username,name:name,img:downloadURL,email:currentUser?.email
        })
        .then( res => {})
        .catch(err => {})
        })
})
```

but because I have group-images I want them to set in a group-item collection but I was thinknig `await setDoc` or something else I should added to make it like a group-item collection in the `owner-item` parent collection but how can I do it?

I search something related to it and it something like this maybe? [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333269/how-to-add-a-collection-to-another-in-cloud-firestore)...but I want `setDoc` because I can change my `document_id`

**UPDATE**
It is something like this....
[LINK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

```
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const messageRef = doc(db, "rooms", "roomA", "messages", "message1");
```

I'm sorry its about document inside of collection...let say

```
await setDoc(..., {
   group_item: {},
   single_item: {},
}
```

based on my old snippet just add this new thing... Is this the righht way to do it?
or something like subcollection you know what I mean.

**UPDATE 2**
let say I have `owner-items`

```
await setDoc(doc(db,`owner-items`,`${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`),{
    group_items:[{
        id:1,
        img:file-image
    }], 
    single_item:[{
        id:1,
        img:file-image
    }]
})
```

Comment: Can you show a diagram of the exact result you are looking for? It’s not very easy to understand what is your exact goal. We add a collection to either the root of the DB or to a document. We cannot add a collection to a collection. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: Sorry but is still not clear to me what is your exact goal. You write "I want them to set in a group-item collection" and then `await setDoc(..., {group_item: {},single_item: {},}` so I have the feeling you are mixing-up collections and field of type map. Try to draw a diagram showing your requirements.

Comment: ok see the update again..

Comment: Ok, so instead of saving the group_items in an Array in the Firestore document, you would like to save them in a sub-collection of this Firestore doc. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes thats right  sir

Comment: Is that right sir or not? I want to use it in something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your answer and comments, the following, using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), should do the trick.

```
import { writeBatch, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const batch = writeBatch(db);

const parentDocRef = doc(db, `owner-items`, `${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`);
batch.set(parentDocRef, {
    single_item: [{
        id: 1,
        img: file - image
    }]
});

const group_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        img: file - image
    },
    {...}
];

group_items.forEach(elem => {
    const groupItemDocRef = doc(db, `owner-items`, `${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`, 'group-items');
    batch.set(groupItemDocRef, {
        item: elem
    });
});

await batch.commit();
```

Note that a batched write can contain up to 500 operations, so your `group_items` array shall have maximum 499 elements.

Comment: Is there something better than this that doesn't have limit?

Comment: You can use ˋPromise.all()ˋ